# Ssh dsa key authentication fails

Tags: authentication, ssh, dsa

I'm trying to log to openssh server installed in cygwin using a dsa key file generated using:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

I have copied my key to authorized_keys using:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa ltonon@localhost
```

I also configured ssh server in /etc/sshd_config (everything else was commented out by default):

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

In /etc/ssh_config (everything else was commented out by default):

```
Host *
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

Now when I try to log in using:

```
ssh -vvvv -i .ssh/id_dsa ltonon@localhost
```

I have the following:

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'ltonon'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ltonon/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ltonon/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:3kIsOo83GqltRfLJY2uSGhsQZDVcY+BoTgl+YqvWYns
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ltonon/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ltonon/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ltonon/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: .ssh/id_dsa (0x60005ff20), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: .ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authentication failed.
```

I'm lost here... Can you help me checking what I missed?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The client is configured correctly -- the key is successfully tried:

```
debug1: Offering DSA public key: .ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
```

but the key is rejected by server. Check that the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is in the server and it has correct permissions (andalso the parent directories) and that you restarted the `sshd` service on the server after changing the configuration.

If that will not help, open the server `sshd_config`, put there `LogLevel DEBUG3`, restart the `sshd` service, try to connect once more and have a look into the logs.

But really, you SHOULD NOT be using DSA keys!

Comment: Hi Jakuje, thanks for your response.
I did what you recommended and still got no success. which logs are you talking about here? I went to /var/log/sshd.log and it's empty. maybe somewhere else?

Regarding rights, I tried with "chmod 777 .ssh" and still the same error.

I also tried checking the key: ssh-keygen -i -f /home/ltonon/.ssh/id_dsa
and got: "decode blob failed: invalid format"

Comment: Do not use `chmod 777` without thinking. Ever! https://www.nixcraft.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/chown-chmod-2.png The permissions for that directory should be 700 otherwise everyone could write his public key to your home directory and access your machine!

Comment: Yes yes I know :) It's just for the sake of testing here. I also tried with RSA keys and I have the same problem.

Any clue? Again I'm using cygwin here. I'm working on and old app that makes connection to ssh server using keys (that's why I wanted to setup "quickly" a ssh server on my local machine)

Comment: The server logs. Where they are, depends on what system is it.

Comment: according to uname -a:
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 TLS-1740 2.8.0(0.309/5/3) 2017-04-01 20:47 x86_64 Cygwin